# Angular8 radio button checked function running unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, angular

I am running an Angular 8 web app, with some logic like below:
HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of selectedItems;">
  <input type="radio"
         [(ngModel)]="mySelectedItem"
         [value]="item.key"
         (ngModelChange)="setChangedItem($event)"
  />
  {{item.name}}
</div>

<tr *ngFor="let additionalItem of additionalItems">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" [value]="myAdditional" [checked]="setAdditionalItems(additionalItem)">
      </td>
      <td>{{additionalItem.name}}</td>
      <td>
</tr>
```

The function call `setAdditionalItems` gets called when I change the radio button (which is not expected). Found in component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  //additionalItems: any[]=[];
  myAdditional='';
  primaryItemType: any[]=[];
  arrayStuff: any[]=[];

  selectedItems = [
    {name: 'FirstVal', key: 1, additionalInfo: 'The is first in the row'},
    {name: 'SecondVal', key: 2, additionalInfo: 'The is second in the row'},
  ];

  additionalItems = [
    {name: 'ThirdVal', key: 3, additionalInfo: 'The is third in the row'},
    {name: 'FourthVal', key: 4, additionalInfo: 'The is fourth in the row'},
    {name: 'FifthVal', key: 5, additionalInfo: 'The is fifth in the row'},
  ];

  mySelectedItem = this.selectedItems[0].key

  setAdditionalItems(additionalItem){
    console.log("ping!", additionalItem)
  }

  setChangedItem(changedItem){
    //some logic
    console.log('setChangedItem', changedItem)
    this.setTypeByItem(changedItem)
}

setTypeByItem(changedItem){
  this.primaryItemType = this.arrayStuff.filter(matchItem => {
    if(matchItem.key === changedItem){
      return matchItem.matchValue
    }
  });
  return this.primaryItemType
  }
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? I don't see any other calls to the function calling `setChangedItem` or `setAdditionalItems`. This may be a bug as a result of something else in my code, since many things in this codebase (not written by me) are tightly coupled.

**Stackblitz**
https://angular-qsiqor.stackblitz.io/

Comment: have you used the same "mySelectedItem" ngModel for any other attributes in that respective html?

Comment: no, it is just in the one spot listed in the radio button

Comment: Is "setChangedItem($event)" function by accidentally calls this func "setAdditionalItems(additionalItem)"?

Comment: No, I don't see any reference to that function outside of the original call

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz?

Comment: can you show `setChangedItem($event)` method's body ?

Comment: `[checked]="setAdditionalItems(additionalItem)` is that a typo?

Comment: https://angular-qsiqor.stackblitz.io/ is the stackblitz link - it wont load for me but I don't know if that is a stackblitz problem or not

Comment: No, I cant let me upload a stackblitz with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your [checked] data binding directive. If you want to activate a method when the checkbox is clicked, you need the (change) directive.

Here is the Stackblitz. Hope this works for you, tell me if not.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnhbsn